# How to reset default ssh password in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

When I trying to connect via ssh to localhost as root, ssh don't accept my current password. How can I reset ssh password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `ssh` disables root login: you are expected to log in as user and then use `su` or `sudo` to become root.

This is an extra security step: if an invader knows or discovers the user password, he can `ssh` the machine but not become root.

That said, if you want to disable this behaviour, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line `PermitRootLogin Yes`.

Comment: +1. Although I can't remember what the standard Ubuntu policy on this is, and I don't have an Ubuntu installation handy at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

On the machine you want to log into, as a non-root user, type:

```
sudo passwd root
```

And you'll be prompted for a new password (after you type your own non-root password)

One little note: there's no such thing as an ‘ssh password’. SSH (unless you set it up in very specific ways, all of which are fairly complex and totally beyond the scope of the question), authenticates against the standard Unix user database (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`). You'll be changing root's own password.